# qtip bubble styling

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, qtip

I just picked up qtip2 plugin for JQuery and can't seem to get the style to work according to their examples. Perhaps I am not understanding something?

This is their example for loading the 6 default available themes, but it does not change anything whether I use cream, red, dark, light, blue or green. I just keep getting the default cream theme. These should have also already been available and usable since qtip 1x?

```
$("jqueryselector").qtip({
   content: 'Dark themes are all the rage!',
   style: { 
      name: 'dark' // Inherit from preset style
   }
});
```

My code is as follows in the JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('a['title']).qtip({style:{name:'red',tip:true}}); // picked up from the getting started page
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That way of styling the tooltip applies to the [original version](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) of `qtip` which is now superseded by a newer version. [`qtip2`](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/style/) uses a better class based styling method.

```
$('.selector').qtip({
   content: {
      text: 'I\'m blue... deal with it!'
   },
   style: {
      classes: 'ui-tooltip-blue ui-tooltip-shadow'
   }
});
```

You definitely want to use `qtip2`. It is much improved over `qtip1`.

Comment: yay. They sent me to get qtip2 as 1x was going to be depreciated soon it said, but i never saw the link for the qtip2 examples and docs. Thank you.

Comment: yeah, sadly the documentation currently states [ classes: 'qtip-blue qtip-shadow' ] but if you look @ the logic & styles, you'll need to follow Geoff's comment and use 'ui-tooltip-theStyleNameYouWant'

Comment: @beauXjames this took me *FOREVER* to figure out... I was following their documentation exactly but it didn't work! Do you know where I can find a list of actual usable style classes? All I know now are the blue & shadow from this answer and `ui-tooltip-dark`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing some brackets.

```
$('a['title']).qtip(style:{name:'red',tip:true}); // your code
$('a[title]').qtip({ style: { name: 'cream', tip: true } });  // their code
```

EDIT: I used qtip a few months back and ended up doing this...

```
    style: {
        //name: 'cream',
        tip: true,
        background: '#E6EFF5',
        color: '#297AA8',
        border: {
            radius: 8,
            color: '#bfd8e8'
        }
    }
```

Comment: no sorry, i missed those brackets when putting it here, but they are on my script. Sorry.

Comment: I don't know what the deal is. I even copied their code directly and adjusted just the $("jqueryselector") to match my target elements which is $("a[title]"). Still does nothing other than default cream style square  bubble.

Comment: @robx Please see edit. Maybe it would be better to just define your own styles like my example.

Comment: it's a no go as well. no matter what I do, if i don't end up breaking it, then all i get is the cream style. I thought it might be cache, so deleted that, and even tried in different browsers. Only cream style.